# What to push to Git?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, jsp, github

I'm gaining my first experience with Git and its hosting platforms (GitHub etc).

Say, I create a JSP project in Eclipse with some custom files (*.jsp and *.java) and a bunch of auto-generated project files. I need to install an application server as well.

This is an example JSP project in Eclipse. Only the yellow marked files were generated by me:

[image]

My colleague wants to contribute to that project. I don't know, what system  and what IDE he is going to use.

What exactly do I need to push to Git?
Are only my own files enough? Or do I need to push the entire project, including the files generated by Eclipse?
What if my colleague uses a different operating system, IDE or application server?

Would it make sense to only push the following files?

- `StudentsBean.java`
- `index.jsp`

How would he then need to import them, so that they become executable?

Comment: It depends on whether you use a build tool like Gradle or Maven for your project. If so it is advised to only commit and push the pom.xml and the main / test directories. No IDE specific files, since all use different IDE's.

Comment: @GerbenJongerius: No, we don't use any build tools.

Comment: Then you have to push and commit the IDE project for your colleague to be able to contribute. That being said nowadays it is very common to use either Maven or Graddle for your Java based projects.

Comment: Have you considered using a build tool like `apache-maven` ? It provides a standard project structure and a `pom.xml` file which glues it all together. Then you just commit the pom.xml, source files, and web info. Your colleague checks it out and can build / run your project

Comment: @GerbenJongerius: Ok, `maven` seems to be helpful in my case. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new repo and then while creating a repo select git ignore file and type of that file is java or jsp. Then while pushing it will automatically ignore files which are not needed.

Comment: For more information on .gitignore. Please find the follow the link https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: I have already ignored most of the project files. In my repo there are only the source files (java and jsp). But, as already mentioned, the project won't be executable without the project files.